# Does Young Earth Creationism teach that Adam and Eve only had a concept of morality after the fall?

Tags: adam-and-eve, morality, young-earth-creation, fall-of-man

Does Young Earth Creationism teach that Adam and Eve only had a concept of morality after the fall, once they had eaten from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil?

If so, would they have been unaccountable for their actions before the fall?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! For a quick overview of what this site is all about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). This question, though a good one, is likely to be fairly opinion-based, which isn't what this site is about. Are you interested in the views of any particular branch or denomination of Christianity? That would make it more objectively answerable under the guidelines of this site.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden - thanks for the feedback, it's all new to me! I'll try and re-frame the question.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE and **thank you** for being understanding! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Does Young Earth Creationism teach that Adam and Eve only had a concept of morality after the fall?**

Young Earth Creationism is not often extended to such considerations.

One might assume that since a knowledge of good and evil was obtained after the infraction, the concept of morality was by definition more limited before the more extensive knowledge was acquired.

They did know morality in a more limited sense of knowing that they were not to eat the fruit of the tree.

> Genesis 3:2-3  And the woman said unto the serpent, We may eat of the
>   fruit of the trees of the garden:   But of the fruit of the tree which
>   is in the midst of the garden, God hath said, Ye shall not eat of it,
>   neither shall ye touch it, lest ye die.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If Adam & Eve’s sense of morality was limited to obeying that one command, they would be unaccountable for other actions that were later explicitly outlawed (such as murder, lying, etc). I am assuming that such actions were possible because they had free will. All of which seems to contradict the description of creation being “good”.  

A literalists explanation of the birth of morality has always seemed simplistic to me, and is one of the reasons I struggle with a literal interpretation of Gen 1-3. But perhaps I’m missing something! Thanks again.